# How to use CombineLates when when publishers failure types is not equivalent?

Tags: swift, combine

I have two functions which return **AnyPublisher** with different failure type: **Never** and **Error**. When using these functions in the **CombineLates**, then compilation fails with an error: **Generic struct 'CombineLatest' requires the types 'Error' and 'Never' be equivalent**

#### Function which never fails:

```
func foo() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    Result<Int, Never>
        .success(1).publisher
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

#### Function which sometimes fails:

```
func boo() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> {
    Result<Int, Error>
        .failure(NSError(domain: "d", code: -1))
        .publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

#### foo & boo functions usage:

```
Publishers.CombineLatest(foo(), boo())
```

#### Error generated:

```
Generic struct 'CombineLatest' requires the types 'Error' and 'Never' be equivalent
```

**How to use CombineLates when publisher's failure types are not equivalent?**

Comment: You have to _make_ them equivalent.

Comment: @matt But question how to achieve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you need to match failure types in Combine, for a `Never` failure type, like a `Just` publisher, you'd use `setFailureType(to:)`:

```
let p: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = ...

let p1 = p.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()  // AnyPublisher<Int, Error>
```

For a non-`Never` failure, you'd need to use `.mapError`:

```
let p2 = p1.mapError { CustomError(wrapping: $0) }
           .eraseToAnyPublisher() // AnyPublisher<Int, CustomError>
```

---

So, in your case, if you want to change `foo`'s return value, you'd do:

```
func foo() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> {
    Result<Int, Never>
        .success(1).publisher
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

And if you don't want to change `foo`, but still use with with `bar`, you can do:

```
Publishers.CombineLatest(foo().setFailureType(to: Error.self), boo())
   .map { (f, b) in
     // f and b are Ints, as emitted by foo and bar, respectively
   }
```

Comment: When using your suggested solution foo value becomes Publishers.SetFailureType. I updated my question with 'Possible solution #1' paragraph based on your answer.

Comment: @Ramis, not sure what you mean. See my edit that my clarify things

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setFailureType(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/setfailuretype(to:)) to set the error type of the publisher that never fails, to match the other publisher that does fail:

```
func foo() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    Result<Int, Never>
        .success(1).publisher
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

If you don't want to change `foo`, you can call `setFailureType` on the return value of `foo` too:

```
Publishers.CombineLatest(
    foo().setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher(), 
    boo()
)
```

Comment: But in this case I need to modify foo() function which is not good.

Comment: @Ramis See the edit. Just call it on `foo()`.

Comment: When using your suggested solution foo value becomes Publishers.SetFailureType. I updated my question with 'Possible solution #1' paragraph.

Comment: @Ramis Uhh... `Publishers.SetFailureType<AnyPublisher<Int, Never>, Error>.Output` is exactly the same type as `Int`.